# Conlfluent 4.0 - Error starting kafka-connect with avro support

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am getting lots of exceptions when trying to start kafka-connect with the command:

```
./bin/connect-distributed ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
```

With every single jar in the share/java dir (at least), I get exceptions like this, complaining about bad magic number:

```
[2018-01-30 08:10:47,804] DEBUG could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in url file:/opt/confluent/confluent-4.0.0/./bin/../share/java/kafka/javassist-3.21.0-GA.jar with scanner SubTypesScanner (org.reflections.Reflections:257)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class object from file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:32)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:253)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:202)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:123)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:162)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:70)
Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MANIFEST.MF
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:102)
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:24)
    at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:30)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: bad magic number: 4d616e69
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:825)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:154)
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:100)
    ... 10 more
```

I have configured in the file './etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties' the full path of the plugin dir.

I am running on an Ubuntu Server 16.04, using Confluent oss 4.0.0-2.11, and have tried with no luck both Oracle's JDK and JRE v1.8.0_162 and v9.0.4 and OpenJDK8, being the result exactly the same. However, strangely, the same exact versions, on an Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 start smoothly. I have even tried to copy all the "share/java" dir contents from the machine that is working to the one that does not (recreating the symbolic links inside some of the folders), but it made no difference.

In this same server I can start the kafka-server and the schema registry without problems.

Moreover, running the same command from the Confluent v3.3.0 installation runs perfectly. So, I tried to configure in the './etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties' file of confluent-4.0.0 the plugin.path variable to point to the 'share/java' dir in the confluent-3.3.0 installation. But running the command from the confluent-4.0.0 folder pointing to the confluent-3.3.0 'share/java' dir resulted in the very same chain of exceptions.

Any clues about what could be wrong?? Because I am running out of ideas...

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you trying to start Kafka Connect, or the Schema Registry?

Comment: Kafka-connect, invoking './bin/connect-distributed '

Comment: But the file you're using is in `etc/schema-registry`... Did you try running Connect standalone mode first? Also, you should delete the 3.3.0 folder, or at least not reference it at all in the plugin path if you want it to work correctly... The Confluent quickstart documentation has worked fine for me

Comment: @Randomizer did you solve this?

Comment: I am afraid I didn't. I downgraded to v 3.3.0...